# Logic IF someone is born on the 21 century sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've built a function that calculates age, all personal ID's I get are 10 numbers according to swedish ssn which the format is `650101-1234`. So far in my function it does calculate age, but only for people born `from 1900 to 1999` How would I go about adding the posibility to calcuate the age on persons born from `2000 and forward`

Here is my code for the function.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[Function_AGE] 
(
     @IdNr varchar(13)

) 
     returns int
     as

begin

  Declare @Calc int 

  Set @IdNr = (Select Case when LEN(@IdNr) > 11 
  then cast(left(@IdNr, 8) as date)
  else cast('19'+left(@IdNr,6) as date) end) 

  set @Calc = (select datediff(year,@IdNr,getdate())) 

Return @Calc
end
```

Comment: can you post example of ssn if person birth year is after 2000..?

Comment: question maybe should be how you know that person born after 2000??

Comment: I presume that `650101` indicates a birthdate of Jan 1, 1965. What does a birthdate of Jan 1, 2001 look like?

Comment: Its the same, If a person is over 100 years old XXXXXX-XXXX The '-' gets replaced by a '+' instead. That means persons born after 2000 will have the same personal ID format

Comment: @mhasan It would look like 140401-NNNX for someone born yesterday (the NNN is a sequence num and the X is a checksum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first two digits fall between 00 and 14 and the character in the seventh position isn't a plus sign the person is born after 1999. So you can add if-then-else logic to test for that.

Here's a not too tested example on how to determine brackets, it's far from perfect and is only meant to serve as a hint - and it probably contains errors :)

```
declare @people table (pnr char(11))
insert @people values ('121212-1212'),('121212+1212'),('991212-1212')

select pnr, 
    case 
        when substring(pnr,7,1)='-' 
            and left(pnr, 2) between 00 and left(year(getdate()), 2) 
            then 'young (after 2000)' 
        when substring(pnr,7,1)='+' 
            and left(pnr, 2) between 00 and left(year(getdate()), 2) 
            then 'old 100+ (before 1914)' 
        when substring(pnr,7,1)='-' 
            and not left(pnr, 2) between 00 and left(year(getdate()), 2) 
            then 'normal (between 1914 and 1999)' 
    end as [Age span]
from @people

Result:
pnr         Age span
----------- ------------------------------
121212-1212 young (after 2000)
121212+1212 old 100+ (before 1914)
991212-1212 normal (between 1914 and 1999)
```

Comment: @t-clausen.dk You're correct, I didn't write any logic for it as I don't have access to my SQL Server at the moment, I just wanted to add information on a way to determine whether the person is born after 1999.

Comment: But when you know logic there is only one small step to do it :)

Comment: I've got the answer will print it shortly! Thank you for the tip :9

Comment: @Darka calculating accurate age has NEVER been a small step in sql-server !

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, I've tested it and it works perfectly! Thank you for the tips I've got it helped me along the way. Much appreciated.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[AGE_Function] 
(
@IdNr varchar(13)

) 
returns int
as

begin
If SUBSTRING(@IdNr,1,2) between '20'+'00' and DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) 
     and LEFT(@IdNr,7) =   '-'
  Begin

   Declare @Calc int 

   Set @IdNr = (Select Case when LEN(@IdNr) > 11 
   then cast(left(@IdNr, 8) as date)
   else cast('20'+left(@IdNr,6) as date) end) 

   set @Calc = (select datediff(year,@IdNr,getdate())) 
end

Else
Begin
   Set @IdNr = (Select Case when LEN(@IdNr) > 11 
   then cast(left(@IdNr, 8) as date)
   else cast('19'+left(@IdNr,6) as date) end) 

   set @Calc = (select datediff(year,@IdNr,getdate())) 
end    
   Return @Calc
end
```

Comment: with your calculation a person born 2013-12-31 will be 1 year old the following day

Comment: True! It does not take notice to details only calculates the year, although I'll have to add that logic aswell